# JSONArray[5] not found using Java

Tags: java, arrays, json, exception, jersey

My Json Response is

```
    "results": [
            [
                "2C30AE32-191@Local",
                "Imperva Inc.",
                "SecureSphere",
                "Custom Violation",
                1,
                "",
                "KMB",
                "196.207.98.94",
                "10.10.1.180",
                "10.10.18.14",
                443,
                "",
                7874115,
                "",
                1522716763000,
                "TCP",
                "",
                "",
                ""
            ]
        ]
```

My java Code :

```
           String output = response.getEntity(String.class);

            JSONObject obj = new JSONObject(output);

            JSONArray results = obj.getJSONArray("results");

                JSONArray first = (JSONArray) results.get(1);

                String deviceVendor = (String) first.get(0);

                String deviceProduct =  (String) first.get(1);

                String name = (String) first.get(2);

                String baseEventCount = (String) first.get(3);

                String categoryOutcome = (String) first.get(4);

                String customerName = (String) first.get(5);

                String sourceAddress = (String) first.get(6);

                String destinationAddress = (String) first.get(7);

                String deviceAddress = (String) first.get(8);

                String destinationPort = (String) first.get(9);

                String destinationServiceName = (String) first.get(10);

                String eventId = (String) first.get(11);

                String message = (String) first.get(12);

                String startTime = (String) first.get(13);

                String transportProtocol = (String) first.get(14);

                String categoryBehavior = (String) first.get(15);

                String categoryDeviceGroup = (String) first.get(16);

                String categoryObject = (String) first.get(17);
```

Here, I am taking index number to get the data. when I am parsing it I am getting JSONArray[5] not found exception. How to handle this. if we have a json object we can handle using `.has("string")` but if it is json array how to handle this situation ?

Comment: please show us related codes.

Comment: Note that you've got an array within an array - my guess is that that's the problem, but it's hard to tell when you haven't shown us any code.

Comment: check JSONARRAY LENGTH FITRST THEN ITERATE IT

Comment: @Jon Skeet see code is provided

Comment: And which line is throwing the exception? It would be good to reduce this to a [mcve] and format it as readably as possible, too.

Comment: @sai what is the use of iterating it. It is showing the JSONArray[5] not found.i.e response data is absent in 5th index number. How to handle this?

Comment: But results.get(1) looks like it should be get(0) to me...

Comment: `results.get(1)` is the first array in that array we have list of indexes

Comment: @ThinkSmart First check global array length and then write if else conditions like if(length==5) then continue your code

Comment: @ThinkSmart: Given the Javadoc, I'd expect `results.get(0)` to be the first array, just like you're using `first.get(0)` later...

Answer (score 0):

```
I have use simplejson you can replace the net.sf.JSON    

it's working.

            JSONParser parser = new JSONParser();
            Object obj = parser.parse(new FileReader("C:\\Users\\user\\Desktop\\results.json"));
            org.json.simple.JSONObject jsonObject = (org.json.simple.JSONObject) obj;
            org.json.simple.JSONArray  departures = (org.json.simple.JSONArray)  jsonObject.get("results");    

            for(int i=0;i<departures.size();i++){ 
                System.out.println("all =="+departures.get(0));
                org.json.simple.JSONArray all = (org.json.simple.JSONArray) departures.get(0); 
                System.out.println("test =="+all.get(5));
            }
```